# Trigger - Multiple entries in the inserted table

Tags: sql, triggers

here's the scenario:

When processing a purchase order through our accounting application, it inserts the entry into INVNUM table and then does a few updates on that inserted entry. I have a trigger that will insert a record into another table based on the record insert/update in INVNUM table.

The problem I'm having is the numerous updates it does on that one entry, ***where it seems like the last two updates it does is exactly the same***, thus my trigger inserts two entries because it cant differentiate between the two updates (The data for both matches exactly).

So basically I'm wanting to insert my record based on the last update in INVNUM table for that purchase order.

Here's something I've come up with to try and isolate the last entry in inserted table:

```
Declare cur1 scroll cursor for (select * from Inserted)
  Open cur1

  FETCH LAST FROM cur1
  While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

   Begin      
    Insert into JCTxLines (ID, JobID, iSource)
    Values(3696,2,3)

   End

Close cur1
Deallocate Cur1
```

This code however hangs the system and I need to close out of it.

Not sure if this is the correct way to tackle the problem. I've been researching for a few days now, my understanding of the inserted/deleted tables are still a bit limited.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to FETCH NEXT after the Insert, which is what is causing the Trigger to hang.

You could also try SELECTING TOP 1 FROM INSERTED?

```
DECLARE  int
DECLARE icursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TOP 1 AutoIndex FROM INSERTED
OPEN icursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM icursor INTO  
WHILE @ = 0
BEGIN
     Insert into JCTxLines (ID, JobID, iSource) Values(3696,2,3)
     FETCH NEXT FROM icursor INTO 
END
CLOSE icursor
DEALLOCATE icursor
```

You could even do SELECT DISTINCT FROM INSERTED